# uiimage position with changing text in uibutton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

i need to create a uibutton to activate a dropdown menu with text on left & image on right on the same line with changing texts.

i used the code below to shift the image to right and it works, however the image will bounce left and right or under the text based on the wording of the text.

How can i make sure that the image stays at the same X,Y constantly ?

```
self.moodBut.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -    
self.moodBut.imageView.frame.size.width-10, 0,  
self.moodBut.imageView.frame.size.width+10);
self.moodBut.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,     
self.moodBut.titleLabel.frame.size.width+10, 0, -   
self.moodBut.titleLabel.frame.size.width-10);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i make found out my mistake

this make my image to stay constantly

```
self.moodBut.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -25, 0, 0);
self.moodBut.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 125, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the `imageEdgeInsets` based on the `titleLabel.frame.size` which is dynamic depends on the length of the title. So instead of using `self.moodBut.titleLabel.frame.size.width`, just use some constant value.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @Eric, the arrow still move according to the length of the text with a constant value with imageEdgeInsets   self.moodBut.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -160);

Comment: Sorry @Desmond. I just build a test project, and the result is like what you said. So I am gonna think about it for a while and try to give you a correct answer.